# How to browse the file in asp.net without using the FileUpload and use the button to browse the folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to browse the folders in my drive with the Browse Button instead of using the FileUpload Tool in the asp.net.

Comment: If you don't want to use the fileupload control (I don't know why), you need to create html code with a <input type="file"....

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<input name="myFile" type="file" />
```

Upon submitting, you can retrieve the file contents like this:

```
Request.Files["myFile"]
```